# Send XIB Class from delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a custom cell for my table that has two button for selection; 'Yes' and 'No'.

My table has multiple cell types so I created a XIB and I have two views in the same xib; I select the view for the cell based on the section number.

```
   CellTakeFive *cell =  (CellTakeFive *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellTakeFive"];

    if (cell == nil) {

        if (indexPath.section == 1 || indexPath.section == 2){
            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CellTakeFive" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:1];
        }
        else if (indexPath.section == 0 || indexPath.section == 3)
        {
            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CellTakeFive" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        }
    }
```

Now I set same delegate for 'Yes' and 'No' selection for both button in both XIB. I call it on click of `Yes` and `No` tap.

```
- (IBAction)onClickSelection:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate selectionWasTapped:self tab:[sender tag]];
}
```

Now I have a different design in both cell so when I click on Cell1(tag set to:1) delegate send self and delegate called on my table class.

But problem is that sometimes delegate send wrong cell to self and I get wrong cell in table class.

Here is my delegate Method :

```
- (void)selectionWasTapped:(CellTakeFive *)cell tab:(int)tag
{

    selectedButtonTag = tag;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tblList indexPathForCell:cell];

    NSLog(@"-----%i -- %i ----",indexPath.section,indexPath.row);

    [_tblList beginUpdates];
    [_tblList reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [_tblList endUpdates];
}
```

What is the issue there? How do I send specific cell on click of button.?

Comment: The delegate sends `self`, so it can't send the wrong cell.  You should show the delegate method; how do you translate the cell instance back to an index path?

Comment: updated please check.

Comment: Your delegate method looks ok, but you don't do anything with the `tag` to update your data model, so what do you expect the reload of the row to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

### Thanks Who tried.

I solved this by not using dequeue cell. Means i load cell every time when table use cell. I need to call my business logic every time in this situation.

So i remove condition.

```
   CellTakeFive *cell =  (CellTakeFive *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellTakeFive"];

    if (indexPath.section == 1 || indexPath.section == 2){
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CellTakeFive" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:1];
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 0 || indexPath.section == 3)
    {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CellTakeFive" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }
```